# Iframe content causes the iframe to jump inside parent

Tags: html, css, iframe

This must be the most crazy html bug ever! How is it even possible that iframe content can affect the layout of the parent.
Please note that `padding-top: 60px;` should stay, as well as the `width/height 170%;` and bascaly the rest of the code should be as it is right now.

There is no reason for this jump to happen.

Again, the `transform: scale(0.6) translate(-33.5%, -33.5%);` is a crucial part of this code, and it must stay.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

._inner_frame_ {
  margin: 0;
  width: 170%;
  height: 170%;
  transform: scale(0.6) translate(-33.5%, -33.5%);
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}

._outer_ {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 800px;
  height: 650px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="_outer_">
  <iframe tabindex="-1" role="presentation" src="https://www.labuttiga.it/en" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" referrerpolicy="origin" scrolling="no" class="_inner_frame_"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is related to the way the browser handles scaling and positioning with iframes. When you use `transform: scale(0.6) translate(-33.5%, -33.5%);`, it applies a transformation to the iframe, and this could affect the positioning in an unexpected way.

Please use this solution and let me know the status.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

._inner_frame_ {
  margin: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 975px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: -60px;
  left: -60px;
}

._outer_ {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 800px;
  height: 650px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="_outer_">
    <iframe tabindex="-1" role="presentation" src="https://www.labuttiga.it/en" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" referrerpolicy="origin" scrolling="no" class="_inner_frame_"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

Adjust the values as needed to fit your layout requirements.

Comment: Thanks! Also looks like you missed the last part of my question about that: Please note that padding-top: 60px; should stay, as well as the width/height 170%; and bascaly the rest of the code should be as it is right now. The transform: scale(0.6) translate(-33.5%, -33.5%); is crucial part of this code.

Answer (score 0):

The web view response exactly according to your instruction. The height length given to iframe is on a high side, beyond the parent container. Reduce the iframe height to 160% or 165%.
I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're facing an issue where the content inside an iframe is affecting the layout of its parent container. This can happen because of the way transformations and scaling are applied.

The `transform: scale(0.6) translate(-33.5%, -33.5%);` you're using on the iframe is crucial, but it can lead to unexpected behavior when combined with scaling and positioning.

To resolve this issue, you can try applying the transformation directly to the content inside the iframe, rather than the iframe itself. Here's how you can do it:

1. Apply the transformation to a nested `div` within the iframe.
2. Place the content of the iframe inside this nested `div`.

By doing this, you can control the scaling and translation of the iframe's content without affecting the layout of the parent container, preventing the jumping issue.

Here's the updated code:

```
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

._outer_ {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 800px;
  height: 650px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

._inner_frame_ {
  margin: 0;
  width: 170%;
  height: 170%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}

._inner_content_ {
  transform: scale(0.6) translate(-33.5%, -33.5%);
}
```

```
<div class="_outer_">
  <iframe tabindex="-1" role="presentation" src="https://www.labuttiga.it/en" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" referrerpolicy="origin" scrolling="no" class="_inner_frame_">
    <!-- Apply transformation to the content within the iframe -->
    <div class="_inner_content_">
      <!-- Place the content of the iframe here -->
    </div>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy